# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context error SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, swiftui

I made a Neumorphic-style view with a title and a neumorphic button. The view changes when I turn on dark mode in the preview code.
I then decided to make a toggle that'll switch dark mode on or off. I unfortunately haven't found a way to give the toggle its functionality (but it shouldn't be creating any errors), and I get this error. I have a whole struct for the Neumorphic style before, which is why you might see terms you don't know. When I remove the toggle, the error disappears.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    @State private var isToggle : Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            VStack {

                Text("Neumorphism") <- Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
                    .font(.system(size: 32,
                                  weight: .bold,
                                  design: .rounded))
                    .padding(20)

                Button("Hello world", action: { })
                    .padding(20)

            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,
                   minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity,
                   alignment: .center)
                .background(backgroundColor)
                .buttonStyle(NeumorphicButtonStyle(colorScheme: colorScheme))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Toggle(isOn: $isToggle) {
                 Text("Dark Mode") <- How could I make this turn on and off dark mode?

            }
        }

    }
    var backgroundColor: Color {
        switch colorScheme {
        case .light: return NeumorphicButtonStyle.Appearance().lightColor
        case .dark: return NeumorphicButtonStyle.Appearance().darkColor
        @unknown default: return NeumorphicButtonStyle.Appearance().lightColor
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
    }
}
```

Comment: No errors (when removed non-available NeumorphicButtonStyle-dependent parts) is observed. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly suggest to separate the View and the logic of the View. A common approach is the [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) concept. I've incorporated this concept in the following example (tested with Xcode 11.3.1):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var darkModeActivated: Bool
    @Published var backgroundColor: Color

    private var sink: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        self.darkModeActivated = false
        self.backgroundColor = Color.white

        self.sink = self.$darkModeActivated.sink() { value in
            if value {
                self.backgroundColor = Color.black
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = Color.white
            }
        }
    }

    public func toggleDarkmode() {
        self.darkModeActivated.toggle()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Neumorphism")
                    .font(.system(size: 32,
                                  weight: .bold,
                                  design: .rounded))
                    .padding(20)

                Button("Hello world", action: { self.viewModel.toggleDarkmode() })
                    .padding(20)
                Button("Hello world2", action: { self.viewModel.darkModeActivated.toggle() })
                    .padding(20)

            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity,
                   minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity,
                   alignment: .center)
                .background(self.viewModel.backgroundColor)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            Toggle(isOn: self.$viewModel.darkModeActivated) {
                 Text("Dark Mode")
            }
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(viewModel: .init())
            .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)
    }
}
```

In the example the View binds directly against the variables `darkModeActivated` to set the state of the toggle button and `backgroundColor` to store the color of the background. Simply spoken, you use the `$` prefix in `self.$viewModel.darkModeActivated` if you change the value of the variable from within the view. A comprehensive explanation can be found [here](https://troz.net/post/2019/swiftui-data-flow/). The logic what happens if the state changes is fully handled by the ViewModel.

The toughest part in the example above was clearly to get notified when the value of `darkModeActivated` changes. Therefore, I've used the Combine framework to attach a subscriber, as proposed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/published).

Using a normal button to activate the dark mode also pretty easy. Just call a ViewModel function from within the button's action closure. Or directly toggle the value like in the example above.

Comment: This is perfect! Works great. How do you think could I incorporate this into the button itself?

Comment: What do you mean with 'into the button itself'? Would you like to have a similar behavior with your "Hello World"-Button?

Comment: Yes, so that every time I tap the button, it toggles the colour mode, like the toggle switch.

Comment: That is pretty easy. I've edited the example in my answer above.